# C - crash when running this application

Tags: c, string, pointers, crash, char

Where is the problem? When running, the application crashes...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void test(char* x) {
    (*x)++;
}

int main() {
    char* x = "xD";
    test(x);
    puts(x);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give more details. How does it crash? What happen when you execute this code? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: You have changed the string literal.

Comment: search for string literals in C…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Trying to modify a string literal that is stored in a read-only memory adress, because with `char* x = "xD";` you declare a pointer to that kind of data. use this `char x [] = "xD";` instead, that is NOT a pointer, is an array that you are allowed to modify because it is stored in the stack. or if you want to use a pointer you need to allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 1):

it crashes in the line `(*x)++;` because `x` Points to a read only Memory due to the Definition `char* x = "xD";`.

Change it to `char x[] = "xD";`. so `x` is an Array and it´s values can be changed